Error using pgloader to migrate from MySQL to Postgres
I have MySQL and Postgres servers on Linux on the same machine. I'm migrating the MySQL database to Postgres by using pgloader. Below is my script.
LOAD DATABASE
    FROM mysql://master:password@127.0.0.1:3306/naqaba_portal
    INTO postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:5432/pg_gsc_v2

WITH include no drop, create tables, create indexes, reset sequences, data only;

but it is giving an error.
root@WOQOOF:~# pgloader migrate.load
2024-07-06T08:07:50.008000+08:00 LOG pgloader version "3.6.2"
2024-07-06T08:07:50.100003+08:00 LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://move@127.0.0.1:3306/naqaba_portal {1007FAB923}>
2024-07-06T08:07:50.100003+08:00 LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/pg_gsc_v2 {1007FAC643}>
KABOOM!
FATAL error: pgloader failed to find anything in schema "naqaba_portal" in target catalog.
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   pgloader failed to find anything in schema "naqaba_portal" in target catalog.

It says it is not able to find anything in the target schema. I created a database in Postgres and created a schema.
I have double checked the schema is created, Postgres is running. I have given all privileges to the schema but still having this error.

Try running with --debug and show us the output (edit it into your question).

I'm going to say it is this data only. Per here pgloader MySQL: data only When this option is listed pgloader only issues the COPY statements, without doing any other processing.  In other words the tables have to already exist and that is what pgloader is complaining about here pgloader failed to find anything in schema "naqaba_portal" in target catalog.
